# How to transfer access table to a CSV file?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a syntax error with code below, although I have created a specification name I can't export my access table to a CSV file.

Can you help me find what I'm doing wrong, please?

```
DoCmd.TransferText(AcTextTransdertype:= acExportDelim, 
Specificationname:="bah" , TableName:="average", 
FileName:="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Folderx\export.csv", 
HasFieldNames:=True)
```

Comment: ```DoCmd.TransferText AcTextTransdertype:=acExportDelim, Specificationname:="bah", TableName:="average", Filename:="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Folderx\export.csv", HasFieldNames:=True``` Get rid of the parenthesis you aren't returning anything to a variable.

Comment: Another method would be to manually extract it - with right click on the table you wish to export > text file. If the extract needs to be repeated, you can save the export step and retrieve it on the "external data" tab > "Saved exports" button. Saved exports can also be called with vba with `DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport SavedImportExportName:=aName`